# INSERT and transaction serialization in PostreSQL

Tags: postgresql, transactions, isolation-level

I have a question. Transaction isolation level is set to serializable. When the one user opens a transaction and INSERTs or UPDATEs data in "table1" and then another user opens a transaction and tries to INSERT data to the same table, does the second user need to wait 'til the first user commits the transaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, no.  The second transaction is inserting only, so unless there is a unique index check or other trigger that needs to take place, the data can be inserted unconditionally.  In the case of a unique index (including primary key), it will block if both transactions are updating rows with the same value, e.g.:

```
-- Session 1                           -- Session 2
CREATE TABLE t (x INT PRIMARY KEY);
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1);
                                       BEGIN;
                                       INSERT INTO t VALUES (1);  -- blocks here
COMMIT;
                                       -- finally completes with duplicate key error
```

Things are less obvious in the case of updates that may affect insertions by the other transaction.  I understand PostgreSQL does not yet support "true" serialisability in this case.  I do not know how commonly supported it is by other SQL systems.

See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/mvcc.html

Comment: hm.. so if i had a primary key in this table unique index check will be performed and second user will be blocked?

Comment: In my experience, quite a lot of tables do have unique indexes.

Comment: the second transaction blocks only because it's trying to insert a duplicate key. If the keys didn't clash, there would be no blocking.

Answer (score -1):

The second user will be blocked until the first user commits or rolls back his/her changes.